# split a log text using a regex, ignoring first match

Tags: java, regex, split

I have the following piece of log text, which I would like to split using a regular expression of **# User@Host**. I am using Java regex lib functions.

```
# Time: 160204  1:56:31
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:     3
# Query_time: 0.000142  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1454579791;
SELECT DATABASE();
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:     3
# Query_time: 0.001254  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
use test;
SET timestamp=1454579791;
# administrator command: Init DB;
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:     3
# Query_time: 0.000441  Lock_time: 0.000077 Rows_sent: 4  Rows_examined: 4
SET timestamp=1454579791;
show databases;
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:     3
# Query_time: 0.000207  Lock_time: 0.000074 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1454579791;
show tables;
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:     3
# Query_time: 0.000537  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1454579791;
;
```

If I do this, I get the following 6 strings.

String 1:

```
# Time: 160204  1:56:31
```

String 2:

```
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:     3
# Query_time: 0.000142  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1454579791;
SELECT DATABASE();
```

String 3:

```
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:     3
# Query_time: 0.001254  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
use test;
SET timestamp=1454579791;
# administrator command: Init DB;
```

String 4:

```
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:     3
# Query_time: 0.000441  Lock_time: 0.000077 Rows_sent: 4  Rows_examined: 4
SET timestamp=1454579791;
show databases;
```

String 5:

```
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:     3
# Query_time: 0.000207  Lock_time: 0.000074 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1454579791;
show tables;
```

String 6:

```
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:     3
# Query_time: 0.000537  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1454579791;
;
```

So, using **# User@Host** as split by regex gives back 6 strings. I am actually interested in only five strings, the two first getting combined. So, the result should look like

String 1:

```
# Time: 160204  1:56:31
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:     3
# Query_time: 0.000142  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1454579791;
SELECT DATABASE();
```

String 2:

```
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:     3
# Query_time: 0.001254  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
use test;
SET timestamp=1454579791;
# administrator command: Init DB;
```

String 3:

```
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:     3
# Query_time: 0.000441  Lock_time: 0.000077 Rows_sent: 4  Rows_examined: 4
SET timestamp=1454579791;
show databases;
```

String 4:

```
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:     3
# Query_time: 0.000207  Lock_time: 0.000074 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1454579791;
show tables;
```

String 5:

```
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:     3
# Query_time: 0.000537  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1454579791;
;
```

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just append the first and the second elements after the split:

```
String string1 = splitArray[0] + splitArray[1];
```

Granted, this will only work if you KNOW that the the format will ALWAYS be what you listed. To ensure that this is the case you can add a check that might look like:

```
if(splitArray[0].startsWith("# Time:"){
    String string1 = splitArray[0] + splitArray[1];
}
```

I'm sure there are more elegant ways to accomplish this, but this will work ;)

Comment: Thanks, this would work for this case. However, I would like to have something more generic. To elaborate little more - given a piece of log text, a regex to capture some text (# Time: 160204  1:56:31 in this case from string 1) and a split by regex (say # User@Host), I am trying to check if we could prepend the text # Time: 160204  1:56:31 to all the strings which don't have it (i.e. string 2 to string 5). I am running into problems because I can't figure out a split by regex which gives me only string 2 to string 5.

Comment: Continued... I would like to avoid the need (if possible) to concatenate string 1 and 2 (which would get split by here) as I don't know if it would work generically.